# remove time HH:mm from String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to check if a string is in the following format:

```
sunday, 31.01.2016 00:05 - wednesday, 03.02.2016 23:55
```

And then remove the time.

Result should look like:

```
sunday, 31.01.2016 - wednesday, 03.02.2016
```

I tried a couple of things but I`m not good in regex or with slice and substring...

Comment: Put some code to help us help you.

Comment: i don't need help:  `str.replace(/ \d{2}:\d{2}/g,"")`

Comment: `str.split(/ \d\d:\d\d/).join('')` works for me.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis! I would like to accept your version as the answer!

Comment: Why is this question down voted? Lack of example? I'm just curious...

Answer (score 0):

My regex is rusty so these might be a little over complicated, but they work and hopefully they answer your question.

To check if the input string matches use:

```
var input = 'sunday, 31.01.2016 00:05 - wednesday, 03.02.2016 23:55';
var regex = /^\W*(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day, \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\ \d{2}\:\d{2} \- \W*(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day, \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}$/;

if(regex.test(input)) {
    //Do something with match
}
```

And to remove the time, use:

```
regex = / \d{2}\:\d{2}/g;
input.replace(regex, '');
```